# Gherkin Nested Steps meaning

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am writing Gherkin test cases and Java step definitions in my project. I am new to Gherkin and trying to understand the meaning of nested steps. Can you please help me to understand if  the 2nd scenario given involves nested steps?

In my example, I would like to reuse 1st scenario code in 2nd scenario given statement logic. Is there a best way to reuse or rewrite the logic?
Note: Below example is written just to explain my question. It may not be a good Gherkin.

```
Background:
    Given The application is opened

Scenario: Successful Login
    Given the user name and password are entered
    When login button is clicked
    Then user login is successful

Scenario: Add Address Successful
    Given user login is successful
    And Add Address button is clicked
    And user city, country are entered
    when Submit button is clicked
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested steps refer to calling defined steps inside a "main" one. In your example, the first scenario has the login functionality, which will / can be used in all other scenarios that require the user to be logged in.

So, the second scenario will have a `Given` step which calls the login action / steps of the first scenario. There are multiple ways to do this:

**1.** If you are defining those steps in the same class, it's just a matter of calling the same methods inside a different step / method.

Like so:

```
public class TestStepsOne {

    // Steps from first scenario

    @Given("^the user name and password are entered$")
    public void enterUsernamePassword() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("User and password entered");
    }

    @When("^login button is clicked$")
    public void clickLoginButton() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Clicked login button");
    }

    @Then("^user login is successful$")
    public void isLoggedIn() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Logged in!");
    }

    // All together

    @Given("the user is logged in")
    public void loginSuccessfully() throws Throwable {
        enterUsernamePassword();
        clickLoginButton();
        isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `Given the user is logged in` in any scenario, and it will perform the login action.

**2. Using Picocontainer** -> details [here](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer)

*First you need to add these dependencies to your* `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
    <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You can separate your step definitions.

Like so:

```
public class TestStepsOne {

    // Same as above, without the nested one

}
```

and second class:

```
public class TestStepsTwo {
    private final TestStepsOne testStepsOne;

    public TestStepsTwo(TestStepsOne testStepsOne) {
        this.testStepsOne = testStepsOne;
    }

    @Given("the user is logged in")
    public void loginSuccessfully() throws Throwable {
        testStepsOne.enterUsernamePassword();
        testStepsOne.clickLoginButton();
        testStepsOne.isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

**3. Using** `cuke4duke` -> details [here](https://github.com/cucumber-attic/cuke4duke) , includes examples

Like so:

```
public class CallingSteps extends Steps {
    public CallingSteps(StepMother stepMother) {
        super(stepMother);
    }

    @When("^I call another step$")
    public void iCallAnotherStep() {
        Given("the user is logged in"); // This will call a step defined somewhere else.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would like to try using pico container. In order to use it, should I just add the dependency and have a parameterized  constructor? How does it work? Also my CommonSteps call(or TestStepsOne class in your example) has a parameterized constructor. Will this be handled ?

Comment: Please have a look at the website linked for picocontainer, it explains it better than I could in a comment (also provides implementation examples).